# jQuery Knob animate when scroll from 0 to specific value

Tags: jquery, html

i am fresher and working on jQuery Knob.it is working fine but my issue is when i scroll to knobs section i want to make that animate like 0 to some specific setuation..is there anyway by using another js like(waypoint and etc) please let me knob..thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several jQuery-Plugins to check if an element is scrolled into view, e.g.
[jQuery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview).
As I have already answered a similar question and don't want to copy previous given answer, find more information here: [jquery knob animate on load section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604962/jquery-knob-animate-on-load-section/25333929#25333929)

Fiddle provided in this answer: [jQuery knob animate using jQuery.inview](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/umhtp5d7/) 
using this code:

```
 $(function () {
  $('.dial').knob({
     min: '0',
     max: '100',
     readOnly: true
  });
});

startKnob =  function() {
  $('.dial').animate({
      value: $('.dial').data('number')
  },{
      duration: 950,
      easing: 'swing',
      progress: function () {
                 $('.dial').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
     }
 });
}

$('.startKnob').bind('inview', startKnob);
```

Answer (score 2):

Give some id to your destination position to the div or any tag let's assume you have any div tag at your destination point to which u want your cursor to get scrolled after clicking specifically somewhere..

....

Then,prove the same id in the anchor link on which after clicking u want your cursor to get scrolled...
such as "#x" inside your anchot tag.
So, are almost ready..now only thing u hve to do is just provide following script before your closing body tag...
$('a[href^="#x"]').on('click', function(event) {

```
var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top

    }, 16000);
}
```

});

```
 $('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 1000);
return false;
```

});

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

```
  var target = jQuery(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top -70
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
```

});
});